# Using a Blob Column in this Query Requires that the Query Subject Must Have Either a Key or a Unique Index

Tags: sql-server-2008, blob

I have the following code:

```
SELECT  boo_event 'Orden de Trabajo' ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(boo_person AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]    
    FROM R5BOOKEDHOURS 
    WHERE boo_event = t.boo_event
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' ') Empleados , STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(boo_hours AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]       
    FROM R5BOOKEDHOURS 
    WHERE boo_event = t.boo_event
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' ') Horas
    FROM R5BOOKEDHOURS t
    GROUP BY boo_event
```

And it works perfectly on SQL Server Studio, but when I'm trying to use it on COGNOS Reporting Studio, I'm getting this error:

*-- Using a Blob Column in this Query Requires that the Query Subject Must Have Either a Key or a Unique Index --*

I'm not sure if it's just an error with that tool, or something we could fix changing the code a bit.

Comment: Try changing `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to `NVARCHAR(4000)`

Comment: It works, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to `NVARCHAR(4000)`:

```
SELECT  boo_event 'Orden de Trabajo' ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(boo_person AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]    
FROM R5BOOKEDHOURS 
WHERE boo_event = t.boo_event
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(4000)'),1,1,' ') Empleados , STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(boo_hours AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]       
FROM R5BOOKEDHOURS 
WHERE boo_event = t.boo_event
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(4000)'),1,1,' ') Horas
FROM R5BOOKEDHOURS t
GROUP BY boo_event;
```